# Skia PDF generation in windows environment

Tags: java, pdf, survey, skia

I was able to successfully compile the skia library using the below tutorial. But I'm not sure how to proceed with SKIA PDF generation .

https://www.programmersought.com/article/9073691401/

Some Skia developers ,   Please guide me to how to use Skia for  pdf generation .

My goal : My java backend has to generate a pdf using Skia pdf backend .

Comment: For some examples see https://kyamagu.github.io/skia-python/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @Mihai8 Thanks for the headstart. Can you point me some examples where skia PDF is generated which contains text,images and colours . Looking at the examples in link is not providing much information